# How to scroll list once in android application using Appium and Python

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium, vertical-scrolling

I want to scroll into a list in an Android app using Python and the following code is working for me:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiScrollable(newUiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("India").instance(0));')
```

But this scrolls the list until it doesn't India, but I only want to scroll once.

I tried this one also:

```
el1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@resource-id = 'resource-id' and @index ='1']")
el2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@resource-id = 'resource-id' and @index ='0']")
self.driver.scroll(el1, el2)
```

This also scrolling the list but it is doing a long scrolling, but i want to go to each and every element in the list.

Can anyone tell me how to scroll the list once?

Comment: not sure how `scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("India")` works exactly, but could you try finding the text of the 2nd element amongst the list and perform the same actiion as `scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("<text of 2nd element>")`

Comment: I tried this and worked perfectly for me which i want, i just used the touch action like press and release, as i want to scroll once, so remove release() part from it and then it worked perfectly for me :) 
el1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath")
el2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath>")
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.press(el1).move_to(el2).perform()

Who else want the same, he/she can use the same fundamentals.

Comment: If that be the case, you can share it as an answer to this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below mentioned code and worked perfectly for me which i wants. i just used the touch action like press and release, as i want to scroll once, so remove release() part from it and then it worked perfectly for me :)

```
el1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath>")    
el2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath>")    
action = TouchAction(self.driver)    
action.press(el1).move_to(el2).perform()
```

Who else want the same, he/she can use the same fundamentals.

Answer (score -2):

I have just scrolled, and it awesome. You just need to swipe from bottom to up, when test is running. Try it, it works 100%.